# Run a simple function on radio button select or deselect

Tags: reactjs

I want my code so that whenever you select *or deselect* the first radio button (on the left), the `onChange` function runs (and hides/shows the text depending on whether the left radio is selected).

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

const App = () => {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
  const [hide, setHide] = useState(true);
  const onSubmit = data => console.log(data);
  const onChange = () => {
    console.log('test');
    setHide(!hide);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <input
          name="example"
          type="radio"
          ref={register}
          onChange={onChange}
          value="one"
        />
        <input name="example" type="radio" ref={register} value="two" />
        <input name="example" type="radio" ref={register} value="three" />
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
      <p style={{ display: hide ? 'none' : 'block' }}>radio one selected</p>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

At the moment, the function only runs when selecting the left radio, but when selecting another radio button, the function doesn't run again (and only runs again when clicking on the left radio button again).

How can this be achieved without adding a function to the other 2 selects (that, for example, just change the state of hide)?

Stackblitz demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yelc5o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with most element events onChange exposes the event object. From that you can check the value of the event target

Add the onChange to the other radios and use a conditional in your handler function based on `e.target.value === 'one'` to set the hide state

```js
const Example = () => {
 const [hide, setHide] = React.useState(true);
 
 const onChange = (evt) => {
    console.log(evt.target.value);
    const isOne = evt.target.value === 'one'
    setHide(!isOne);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input name="example" onChange={onChange} type="radio" value="one" />
      <input name="example" onChange={onChange} type="radio"  value="two" />
      <input name="example" onChange={onChange} type="radio" value="three" />
      <p style={{ display: hide ? 'none' : 'block' }}>radio one selected</p>
    </div>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```